# Ruby On Rails: Fetching records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, datarow

I'm looking for a tutorial or a piece of code that can leads me to create a page
where we can find only 10 data rows per page and navigating with Ajax previous/next arrows
and also page number (i.e.: < 1 2 3 ... 10 > ).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Fetching 10 rows is easy with `:limit => 10`, so your question is how to use AJAX?

Comment: If none of the answers you've gotten so far work for you, please add a comment or edit your question telling us why. If one of them does work, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is [Mislav's will-paginate plugin](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). The Readme at that link should explain how to use it.

**Edited:**

There's also a [screencast on RailsCasts about Ajax pagination](http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax). I haven't watched it, but his stuff is usually really high-quality and easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

it's not ajax but maybe it's useful for you... when you use haml and haml_scaffolding in rails it's authomatic the pagination using this kind of sacffolding